# why am i not getting back return value? what am i doing wrong?

Tags: javascript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spZii.png)What am I doing wrong?

```
function publicBusFare(passenger) {
    let busFair = 0;
    if (typeof passenger == 'number') {
        // * Checking people for bus
        if (passenger % 50 != 0) {
            let extraPassengerOfBus = passenger % 50;
            // * Checking People for micro bus
            if (extraPassengerOfBus % 11 != 0) {
                let extraPassengerOfMicro = extraPassengerOfBus % 11;
                // * Checking Extra passenger are exist for public bus.
                if (extraPassengerOfMicro != 0) {
                    // * Calculating The Bus Fair For Extra People...
                    busFair = extraPassengerOfMicro * 250;
```

I'm trying to get return of `busFair` value. I is working when I'm using console.log for function.

```
                    return busFair;
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        console.log("Please provide Number!")
    }
}
publicBusFare(1);
```

Comment: You're calling `publicBusFare` but then completely ignoring the return value. How can you tell you aren't getting the result you want when you don't do anything to look at it?

Comment: i need the busFair value. can you tell me how can I get the value without console log?

Comment: If you don't want to use console.log what do you want to do with the value instead?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you are getting the return value.

What happens when you `console.log(publicBusFare(1))` is that the return value is passed as an argument of the function `console.log`.

If you want to store the value, you need to assign it to a variable.

**Example:**

```
const busFare = publicBusFare(1);
```

Maybe this helps you to understand better:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp

Comment: Thanks, it was a foolish mistake!  :) but really helped me to think about what I was doing wrong! thanks again!